# PHP get source of image by ID, Name, Class, whatever from HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, image

I am trying to get an image from a one site to show on another site through PHP.

Basically, I have a product on website and it has an Img attached to it, so when a customer clicks Buy, I want that Img src to go to the order.php site and be displayed there.

I could write a different order.php site for individual products, but that just seem very inefficient.

I would like something like the:

```
<?php print $_GET["amount"]; ?>
```

accept for the src code.

I have a form like this:

```
<div>
<img class="productImage" src="product.jpg"/>
<form class="submitForm" action="order.php" method="get">
   <input type="number" name="amount" min="1" max="100" value="0" required />
   <input class="submitButton" type="submit" value="Buy" />
</form>
</div>
```

I know that there is a solution with JS:

```
document.getElementById("myImg").src = "anotherImage.gif";
```

but that doesn't get it to the next site and I don't know how I could get it there.

**EDIT**

After the help of  @yvanavermaet , the hidden `<input>` value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="imageUrl" value="product.jpg" />
```

with the PHP:

```
 $_GET["imageUrl"]
```

worked perfectly!

Comment: You could add a hidden input field in your form which contains the url of the image.
<input type="hidden" name="imageUrl" value="product.jpg" />

Then you can do $_GET["imageUrl"] in php

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks